# Run script on Wacom Bamboo button press

Tags: input-devices, wacom, xinput

I have Wacom Bamboo tablet which has some buttons on the device. How can I configure a script to be run when I press one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the tablet drivers first, try [searching in the Wacom site for your model](http://www.wacom.com/customercare/Drivers.aspx) and then download the linux version.

After the installation, you can open the main configuration interface and set the buttons there.

Comment: The tablet is already installed, I can use the pen fully. When I click on map buttons in the Gnome built-in config panel, the screen is empty.

Comment: Well, that's strange, I've not yet installed my tablet on ubuntu, I'm using windows 7 and it seems fine. I'll try installing it on ubuntu.